# Ubuntu takes multiple attempts to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I own a ASUS ROG gaming laptop and recently dual booted ubuntu 19.04 with windows 10. Whenever I select windows from the grub menu, it works fine but when I select ubuntu it takes multiple attempts (around 3) to boot ubuntu. It gets stuck on the ubuntu boot animation and I have to force power off the laptop and try again. Like this, Ubuntu boots in the 2nd or 3rd attempt. Once Ubuntu boots, I get no major problems as such. Can someone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: You didn't mentioned so I'm assuming you didn't install the proprietary graphics drivers. You may want to do just that.

Comment: "Can someone suggest a fix for this?" not with this kind of info. Please try to find the error in the log files in /var/log or onscreen during boot.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielaGarcia. That solved it for me!